# Beamer - combining the ways for creating overlays

Tags: beamer

I want to create a frame with text the reveals itself one item at a time, with a picture at the bottom which changes when new text is revealed. I did the following naive attempt:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item text 1
    \pause
    \item text 2
  \end{itemize}

  \includegraphics<1>[height=40mm]{pic1.jpg}

  \includegraphics<2>[height=40mm]{pic2.jpg}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, this failed; pic1 is not displayed.

I guess the problem is that the includegraphics for pic1 comes after the pause, but how can I place it before the pause and still ensure it will be at the same place as pic2?

Another solution is not to use pause at all, but the alternative I see is using numbers for all the items in the slide, which will be very cumbersome in slides with many items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>(see below for my first answer)</sup>

**Edit:** A more complete and customizable solution (using columns to put images on the left or on the right).

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% put a node on absolute position on the page
% (two compilations is necessary to get a good placement)
% #1: anchor of the page
% #2: shift vector
% #3: anchor of the node
% #4: minimum height of the node
% #5: minimum width of the node
% #6: content
\newcommand\absoluteput[6]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path (current page.#1) ++ (#2)
    node[#3,minimum height=#4,minimum width=#5]{#6};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
% put a node 5mm above the south of the page
% #1: min height
% #2: content
\newcommand\putbottom[2]{\absoluteput{south}{0,5mm}{above}{#1}{0}{#2}}
% put a node 5mm to the left of the east of the page
% #1: min width
% #2: content
\newcommand\putright[2]{\absoluteput{east}{-5mm,0}{left}{0}{#1}{#2}}

% put a node 5mm to the right of the west of the page
% #1: min width
% #2: content
\newcommand\putleft[2]{\absoluteput{west}{5mm,0}{right}{0}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame with images at bottom}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item Pellentesque interdum sapien sed nulla.
    \putbottom{42mm}{\includegraphics<.>[height=40mm]{example-image}}
  \item Proin tincidunt.
    \putbottom{42mm}{\includegraphics<.>[height=30mm]{example-image-a}}
  \item Aliquam volutpat est vel massa.
    \putbottom{42mm}{\includegraphics<.>[height=20mm]{example-image}}
  \item Sed dolor lacus, imperdiet non, ornare non, commodo eu,
    neque. Integer pretium semper justo.
    \putbottom{42mm}{\includegraphics<.>[height=42mm]{example-image-a}}
  \end{itemize}
  \vfill
  \vspace*{47mm} % 5mm (margin) + 42mm (max height of images)
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame with images on the right}
  \begin{columns}

    \column{\linewidth-5mm-47mm} % \linewidth - (margin) - (max width of images)

    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Pellentesque interdum sapien sed nulla.
      \putright{47mm}{\includegraphics<.>[width=40mm]{example-image}}
    \item Proin tincidunt.
      \putright{47mm}{\includegraphics<.>[width=30mm]{example-image-a}}
    \item Aliquam volutpat est vel massa.
      \putright{47mm}{\includegraphics<.>[width=20mm]{example-image}}
    \item Sed dolor lacus, imperdiet non, ornare non, commodo eu,
      neque. Integer pretium semper justo.
      \putright{47mm}{\includegraphics<.>[width=47mm]{example-image-a}}
    \item Proin tincidunt.
      \putright{47mm}{\includegraphics<.>[width=30mm]{example-image-a}}
    \item Aliquam volutpat est vel massa.
      \putright{47mm}{\includegraphics<.>[width=20mm]{example-image}}
    \item Sed dolor lacus, imperdiet non, ornare non, commodo eu,
      neque. Integer pretium semper justo.
      \putright{47mm}{\includegraphics<.>[width=42mm]{example-image-a}}
    \end{itemize}

    \column{47mm} % (max width of images)

  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame with images on the left}
  \begin{columns}

    \column{30mm} % (max width of images)

    \column{\linewidth-5mm-30mm} % \linewidth - (margin) - (max xidth of images)

    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Pellentesque interdum sapien sed nulla.
      \putleft{30mm}{\includegraphics<.>[angle=90,width=30mm]{example-image}}
    \item Proin tincidunt.
      \putleft{30mm}{\includegraphics<.>[width=30mm]{example-image-a}}
    \item Aliquam volutpat est vel massa.
      \putleft{30mm}{\includegraphics<.>[width=20mm]{example-image}}
    \item Sed dolor lacus, imperdiet non, ornare non, commodo eu,
      neque. Integer pretium semper justo.
      \putleft{30mm}{\includegraphics<.>[width=30mm]{example-image-a}}
    \item Proin tincidunt.
      \putleft{30mm}{\includegraphics<.>[width=30mm]{example-image-a}}
    \item Aliquam volutpat est vel massa.
      \putleft{30mm}{\includegraphics<.>[width=30mm]{example-image}}
    \item Sed dolor lacus, imperdiet non, ornare non, commodo eu,
      neque. Integer pretium semper justo.
      \putleft{30mm}{\includegraphics<.>[width=16mm]{example-image-a}}
    \end{itemize}

  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**First answer:**

You can use TikZ to add a picture at absolute place and you can use the  option `<+->` with `itemize` to use *incremental overlay specifications*. I add calls to `vfill` and `\vspace...` to keep space for the images.

You can make

[image]

Here, the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

% put a node 5mm above the bottom of the page
% (two compilations required to get a good placement)
\newcommand\myabsoluteplace[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south] at ([yshift=5mm]current page.south) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item text 1 \myabsoluteplace{\includegraphics<.>[height=40mm]{example-image}}
  \item text 2  \myabsoluteplace{\includegraphics<.>[height=30mm]{example-image-a}}
  \item text 3 \myabsoluteplace{\includegraphics<.>[height=20mm]{example-image}}
  \item text 4  \myabsoluteplace{\includegraphics<.>[height=42mm]{example-image-a}}
  \end{itemize}
  \vfill
  \vspace*{47mm} % 5mm (margin) + 42mm (max images)
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, this looks fantastic.

Answer (score 5):

If I have correctly understood what you are trying to do, I think the following should work

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{draft}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> text1
    \item<2> text2
  \end{itemize}

\includegraphics<1>[height=40mm]{pic1.jpg}
\includegraphics<2>[height=40mm]{pic2.jpg}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As you mention, it means providing the overlay specification for each `\item`, but there can't be so many of them on the same slide (especially with images on the same slide), right?

Answer (score 2):

A weaker answer than Paul's, but one that doesn't require tikz, is the following, where the figures are foo-1.pdf, foo-2.pdf, foo-3.pdf, and so on.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[h]
    \column{3in}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
    \end{itemize}
\column{3in}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \multiinclude[<+>][format=pdf,start=1]{foo}
\end{figure}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```